# Jquery Select element before and Element after remove/add class

Tags: jquery, html, class

I'm trying to remove 2 classes from the div Content:

```
<div class="content">
 <div class="1 hide">class1</div>
 <div class="2">class2</div>
 <div class="3 hide">class3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
 <div class="1 hide">class1</div>
 <div class="2">class2</div>
 <div class="3 hide">class3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
 <div class="1 hide">class1</div>
 <div class="2">class2</div>
 <div class="3 hide">class3</div>
</div>



 <script>
     $( ".content" ).click(function() {
remove classes hide from class 1 and 3 in the content div if clicked on that div 
but leave the other content divs with class 1 and 3 hidden 

     });
    </script>
```

Whats the best way to do this I can't figure out how :(

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/jdvut4pu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a context bases selector like

```js
$(".content").click(function () {
    $(this).find('.hide').removeClass('hide')
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="1 hide">class1</div>
    <div class="2">class2</div>
    <div class="3 hide">class3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="1 hide">class1</div>
    <div class="2">class2</div>
    <div class="3 hide">class3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="1 hide">class1</div>
    <div class="2">class2</div>
    <div class="3 hide">class3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this one works fine! Found out what i did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(".content").click(function () {
    $(this).children().removeClass("hide");
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/71wgL51g/2/)

**References:**

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: im sorry to say but the fiddle isnt working for me and the code isnt working for me either :(

Comment: This is working as it expects. When you click inside `content` remove all `hide` class from children divs. You want to remove class when click on content or on div inside content?

Comment: i want to remove the class when i click on .content i tested it but it doesnt seem to work for me maybe its my browers? google chrome

Comment: browser* instead of browers

Comment: No reason not to work to be honest. The only thing i can imagine is that maybe you have different html structure in your real example.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jdvut4pu/)**

```
 $(".content ").on("click", function () {
    $(this).find('.hide').removeClass('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for classes 1 and 3 using [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). Refine the selector to the [context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) of the clicked content-element.

Try this code:

```
$(".content").click(function () {
    $('.1, .3', this).removeClass("hide");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcxrmwt8/)

Comment: provide some text if possible.